# Old favicon in chat page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, favicon

Chat page still has old favicon (like https://chat.stackoverflow.com).

> [image]

It's not a bug, but seems like confusing thing or is it an intention to leave chat's icon as it was ?

If not, I think it should be fixed.

Comment: Agreed, this should be fixed. The previous icons should be reinstated in all sites.

Comment: I like old too - but my though if that it should be same everywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CDN still has the old version in its cache. I've changed chat's cache breaker to work around that.

Comment: *Jedi hand wave:* This is not the fix you are looking for.